# Populate R matrix from vector based on combined col- and row-name

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to populate a matrix with values from a vector, where the name of each value is a combination of the matrix' col- and row names.

```
set.seed(1001)
mat <- matrix(nrow = 2, ncol = 3, dimnames = list(c("one", "two"), c("house", "tree", "flower")))
vec <- sample.int(10, 5)
names(vec) <- c("one_house", "one_flower", "two_tree", "two_house", "one_tree")
```

The output I'm looking for is this:

```
matrix(c(4, 7, 6, 2, 3, NA), nrow = 2, ncol = 3, dimnames = list(c("one", "two"), c("house", "tree", "flower")))
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I get a different value from seed you showed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can split the `names` of the vector by `_` and do an assignment based on row/column name attributes in the `mat`

```
mat[do.call(rbind, strsplit(names(vec), "_"))] <- vec
```

-output

```
mat
#    house tree flower
#one     7    9      3
#two     8   10     NA
```

Or, if we don't have a dataset to replace, we can construct a `data.frame` and use `xtabs` to reshape the data

```
xtabs(vec ~ V1 + V2, as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(names(vec), "_"))))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the super speedy reply. Works a treat!